# Can't connect to internet through iphone 14 simulator

Tags: ios

A few months ago, I was developing a iOS app with connection to an online API. I picked it up a few hours ago, but I cannot connect the API anymore. In safari on the simulator, I cannot connect to https://google.com or other websites. I get "connection is not secure" warning.

The API is online, I can connect to it through my computer.

I didn't change anything to the API code or the app code, and when I build the app through xcode an deploy it on my iphone device, it works.

I get the following error in xcode:

```
2023-09-12 19:31:06.707581+0200 app[19454:2292385] ATS failed system trust
2023-09-12 19:31:06.707685+0200 app[19454:2292385] Connection 36: system TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9802)
2023-09-12 19:31:06.707795+0200 app[19454:2292385] Connection 36: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9802
2023-09-12 19:31:06.707887+0200 app[19454:2292385] Connection 36: encountered error(3:-9802)
2023-09-12 19:31:06.712100+0200 app[19454:2292385] Task <redacted>.<31> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
2023-09-12 19:31:06.712376+0200 app[19454:2293193] Task <redacted>.<31> finished with error [-1200] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(
    "<cert(0x158e01c00) s: clients3.google.com i: incoggo_ca>",
    "<cert(0x158dfbe00) s: incoggo_ca i: incoggo_ca>"
```

I know I can allow http connections, I already tested it but it isn't working either.

Thanks in advance!